# Aligning form elements in a bootstrap dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a demo of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwCBa/

The form here asks for an email and password, and below that is a "Remember me" checkbox, and a "Forgot Password" link (button).

Here is my problem - the "Forgot password" link is **below** the checkbox. It want it to be on **the same row** as the checkbox, and **right-aligned**.

I've been knocking around with this for a while, and I can't seem to get the "Forgot Password" link where I need it to be. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <label class="checkbox span4"><input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Remember me for 2 weeks</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-link span2">Forgot Password?</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the button inside the 'checkbox' label, and then use `pull-right` on the controls-group like this...

```
<div class="control-group pull-right">
 <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Remember me for 2 weeks  <button type="button" class="btn-link">Forgot Password?</button></label>
 </div>                                 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/XwCBa/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thank you Skelly. Actually I modified your code a bit by moving the pull-right to the "forgot password" link, that way they both align where they should be. But that was basically the answer, to put them both in the label.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Remember me for 2 weeks  <button type="button" class="btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</button></label>
    </div>  
</div>
```